# Broken featured images are uploading from frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have a form at frontend i want to create post from frontend everything works but when i upload featured image , broken featured image is uploading. I saw uploads folder the image exists there but i can't understand why images are breaking while upload ,  any help will be appreciated thanks

here is my code.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_bpem_event_form_response', 'bpem_event_form_response' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_bpem_event_form_response', 'bpem_event_form_response' );

function bpem_event_form_response() {

$title              = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_title']); 
$content            = $_POST['ev_desc'];
$image_url        = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_image']);
$location         = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_location']);
$start_date       = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_start_date']);
$start_time       = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_start_time']);
$end_date         = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_end_date']);
$end_time         = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_end_time']);
$ev_organizer     = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_organizer']);
$ev_organizer_url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_organizer_url']);
$group              = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_group']);


$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
   'post_type'         => 'bpem_event',
   'post_title'        => $title,
   'post_content'    => $content,
   'post_status'       => 'publish'
));


add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_location', $location );
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_startDate', $start_date);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_startTime', $start_time);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_endDate', $end_date);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_endTime', $end_time);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_organizer', $ev_organizer);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_organizer_url', $ev_organizer_url);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_group', $group);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_group_slug', sanitize_title($group));



// Add Featured Image to Post

$imagebase        = basename( $image_url ); 
$image_name       = $imagebase;
$upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); // Generate unique name
$filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

echo "Success";

    wp_die();
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: You don't have to move the file there yourself, that's probably why it isn't working. WP has functions that'll do all the moving and folder creation for you

Comment: Also, your code has no checks on the uploaded file, anybody could upload anything, including PHP shells for hacking your website, child pornography, torrents, large files, malware, etc

Comment: Upload image solution needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of my own question it'll definitely help others to solve same problem.

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_bpem_event_form_response', 'bpem_event_form_response' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_bpem_event_form_response', 'bpem_event_form_response' );



function bpem_event_form_response() {
$title           = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_title']); 
$content         = $_POST['ev_desc'];
$image_url     = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_image']);
$location      = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_location']);
$start_date    = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_start_date']);
$start_time    = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_start_time']);
$end_date      = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_end_date']);
$end_time      = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_end_time']);
$ev_organizer  = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_organizer']);
$ev_organizer_url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_organizer_url']);
$group           = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ev_group']);

$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (

'post_type'     => 'bpem_event',
'post_title'    =>   $title,
'post_content'  =>  $content,
'post_status'   => 'publish'

));

add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_location', $location );
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_startDate', $start_date);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_startTime', $start_time);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_endDate', $end_date);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_endTime', $end_time);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_organizer', $ev_organizer);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_organizer_url', $ev_organizer_url);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_group', $group);
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'evn_group_slug', sanitize_title($group));
echo "Success 1";
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$image = media_sideload_image($image_url, $post_id,"Image",'id');
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image );
echo "Success";

wp_die();
}
```